# (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client ] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling),

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a python script which takes some time to execute. This is called on:

```
add_action('save_post', 'mysave',10,2);
```

on wordpress. I am continuously getting the same error:

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.1.116:51376] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling),
```

Most probably its because I need to increase some execution time properties. Any idea how?